# Access a service on a specific port using SSH Tunnels

Tags: networking, ssh

I have the following scenario:

I need to access a service on a machine (port 9999) from outside the network using ssh tunneling. The IP address of the machine is 10.0.0.7. I have access to a VM (IP: 10.0.0.3), which I can access from outside the network using ssh on port 22.

How can I access the service (that's running on port 9999 on 10.0.0.7) from my home network?

I have tried reverse forwarding the port but no luck.

Also, we have a few of these polling machines on the network that all run on port 9999 (IP's ranging from 10.0.0.6 to 10.0.0.15). Is a possible to access all of them as well?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you mean no luck? Reverse tunnelling should work: ssh -L9999:10.0.0.7:9999 10.0.0.3 - and then localhost:9999 should forward through to 10.0.0.7:9999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SSH's standard tunnelling should work:

```
ssh -L9999:10.0.0.7:9999 10.0.0.3
```

You should then be able to connect to `localhost:9999` and that will be equivalent to connecting to `10.0.0.7:9999`. If you want to do this for lots of hosts, you can do lots of `-L` statements, but the first port has to be unique:

```
ssh -L9999:10.0.0.7:9999 -L9998:10.0.0.8:9999 10.0.0.3
```

Then you have `localhost:9999` and `localhost:9998`. To speed this up, you can add the following to your `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host 10.0.0.3
    LocalForward 9999 10.0.0.7:9999
    LocalForward 9998 10.0.0.8:9999
    LocalForward 9997 10.0.0.9:9999
    LocalForward 9996 10.0.0.10:9999
    LocalForward 9995 10.0.0.11:9999
    LocalForward 9994 10.0.0.12:9999
    LocalForward 9993 10.0.0.13:9999
```

Then `ssh 10.0.0.3` will automatically set up those tunnels for you.